# Android image from gallery orientation

Tags: android

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(filePath);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            uploadFilePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            uploadFilePath = decodeFile(uploadFilePath, 512, 512);
        }
        cursor.close();

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);

            if(sendImageType.equals("profile")){
                imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if(sendImageType.equals("cover")){
                imgCover.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath);
                }
            }).start();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Decode File :

```
private String decodeFile(String path,int DESIREDWIDTH, int DESIREDHEIGHT) {
    String strMyImagePath = null;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    try {
        // Part 1: Decode image
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeFile(path, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingUtilities.ScalingLogic.FIT);

        if (!(unscaledBitmap.getWidth() <= DESIREDWIDTH && unscaledBitmap.getHeight() <= DESIREDHEIGHT)) {
            // Part 2: Scale image
            scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingUtilities.ScalingLogic.FIT);
        } else {
            unscaledBitmap.recycle();
            return path;
        }

        // Store to tmp file

        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File mFolder = new File(extr + "/TMMFOLDER");
        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            mFolder.mkdir();
        }

        String s = "tmp.png";

        File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);

        strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        scaledBitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }

    if (strMyImagePath == null) {
        return path;
    }
    return strMyImagePath;

}
```

Hi, i have an image uploader, i am uploading image from android gallery to my server. But some photos load horizontally. How can i understand, photo is horizontal or vertical and how do i rotate.

It look below, after upload :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check the orientation of an image

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

switch(orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

To rotate the image use

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    try {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public  static  Bitmap getOriententionBitmap(String filePath){
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
    try
    {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int angle = 0;

        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            angle = 90;
        }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            angle = 180;
        }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            angle = 270;
        }

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(angle);

        Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), mat, true);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
    }
    return myBitmap;
}
```